# chrome Ajax call problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an Ajax call as below

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<%= Url.Content("~/Post/GetItems/")%>"  + userId,                             
                    success: function(data) {  
alert(data.rows.lenth)

                    },
                    error:function(response, status, error) { 

                       }               
                });   
[/code]   
and at controller i have

[code]
public JsonResult GetItems(.......)
{
..............
............

  return Json(new {  rows = from tag in Nodes select new { level = tag.Depth } }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I can access data.rows.length in all browsers
but In chrome data.rows is null

what can i do to solve this?

Comment: I had this problem. Try running the ajax page on chrome, it might gives you some hints. My problem was the first time you go to the webpage you get a null and it does it every time you start chrome, ie close the chrome and open it again. It turns out that the library I was using was doing something funky with the connection to oracle db.

Comment: You've used wrong tags to format code in your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably unrelated but try like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<%= Url.Action("GetItems", "Post") %>',
    data: { userId: userId },
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result.rows.length);
    },
    error: function(response, status, error) { 

    }               
});
```

and:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetItems(string userId)
{
    ...
    var rows = from tag in Nodes select new { level = tag.Depth };
    return Json(new { rows = rows }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Also make sure that the controller action sends some values over there. Maybe start by hardcoding them first to ensure that the AJAX call works:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetItems(string userId)
{
    return Json(new 
    { 
        rows = new[]
        {
            new { level = 1 },
            new { level = 2 },
            new { level = 3 },
        } 
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: ACTUALLY THE problem was not with this area .i was just setting a value like $('#a').val(<%=Model.value%>) but it should be $('#a').val('<%=Model.value%>') i missed the '..'. That was causing problem only in chrome :)